# Excel Macro - Update a row of information in a different sheet based on matching multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have been searching for a while a solution to this problem, but without much success. I need a macro that allows me to update the data in a different sheet based on matching criteria.

For example, we have in sheet 1:

[image: Sheet 1 data]

and you transfer the data from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2.

[image: Sheet 2 with records]

However, after certain period of time the information changes and you would like to update it by replacing the original data with new information:

[image: New information Sheet 1]

In order to find the information in sheet 2, which can be very long log with different data, you use information from one row and Columns 1 to 6, and once found, you transfer details of that row and from columns 1 to 11 from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2. You continue row by row in Sheet 1 until you have compared and updated all rows. If the criteria was not found, then it should tell you.

I have tried in different ways, but I cannot get the whole structured.

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239)

Comment: "I have tried in different ways" - which ones? What formulas have you tried?

Comment: Data 1


Column 1,Column 2,Column 3,Column 4,Column 5,Column 6,Column 7,Column 8,Column 9,Column 10,Column 11
44197,44285,Charles,Smith,Salary,All,30000,1,A,HJ2,20
44197,44285,Charles,Smith,Marital Status,All,Married,5,B,HJ2,20
44197,44285,Charles,Smith,City,All,London,3,GB,HJ2,20
44378,44560,Norman,Paddington ,Salary,All,50000,1,B,HJ3,20
44378,44560,Norman,Paddington ,Marital Status,All,Single,5,A,HJ3,20
44378,44560,Norman,Paddington ,City,All,Manchester,3,GB,HJ3,20

Comment: Data 2
Column 1,Column 2,Column 3,Column 4,Column 5,Column 6,Column 7,Column 8,Column 9,Column 10,Column 11
44197,44285,Charles,Smith,Salary,All,400000,1,B,HJ2,20
44197,44285,Charles,Smith,Marital Status,All,Divorsed,6,B,HJ2,20
44197,44285,Charles,Smith,City,All,London,3,GB,HJ2,20
44378,44560,Norman,Paddington ,Salary,All,60000,2,C,HJ3,20
44378,44560,Norman,Paddington ,Marital Status,All,Single,5,A,HJ3,20
44378,44560,Norman,Paddington ,City,All,Manchester,3,GB,HJ3,20

Comment: The goal is to edit your question to make the original question better and better. For this reason do not add requested info or improvements as comments, but use the EDIT button to make the question itself better with those changes.